# Spring-Boot tests throw PSQLException when running all tests

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, junit, hikaricp, testcontainers

I am working on a springboot project that uses Testcontainers with PostgreSQLContainer for testing. The test containres are set with the [Singleton pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/) with reuse set to `true`.

The tests were working fine until I added some new tests and suddenly some other unrelated tests started to throw the org.postgresql.util.PSQLException exception.
Specifically, the same 2 test classes with a total of 3 test cases always throw this exception whenever I run all tests together with `mvn test`.

```
2022-10-03 17:12:55.218  INFO 97454 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean transactionId: 163 userId:  : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-03 17:12:55.221  INFO 97454 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       transactionId: 163 userId:  : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-10-03 17:12:55.222  INFO 97454 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       transactionId: 163 userId:  : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-10-03 17:12:55.232  WARN 97454 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   transactionId: 163 userId:  : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@10625b21 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:881) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getMetaData(PgConnection.java:1313) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.getMetaData(ProxyConnection.java:380) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.getMetaData(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.util.DriverUtils.getDriverName(DriverUtils.java:48) ~[rider-core-1.31.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.connection.RiderDataSource.checkDbType(RiderDataSource.java:175) ~[rider-core-1.31.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.connection.RiderDataSource.init(RiderDataSource.java:96) ~[rider-core-1.31.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.connection.RiderDataSource.<init>(RiderDataSource.java:53) ~[rider-core-1.31.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.core.dataset.DataSetExecutorImpl.getRiderDataSource(DataSetExecutorImpl.java:919) ~[rider-core-1.31.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.database.rider.junit5.DBUnitExtension.beforeTestExecution(DBUnitExtension.java:60) ~[rider-junit5-1.31.0.jar:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks$4(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:183) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
```

I should mention that these 3 tests don't even use any repository or any direct db access, but they all extend the abstract class that references the Testcontainer class

The weird thing is, whenever I run the same failed tests in isolation, i.e. `mvn test -Dtest=ClassNameTest` (or with the help of my IDE UI) they succeed just fine.

I found some other answers online whit suggestions to change some datasource properties and play with the parameters, I tried multiple suggesions but I always get the same resuls.

**Update 1:**

After further investigation, I noticed that:

1- The failing tests will actually change depending on the order that the tests are run, the last few tests are always the ones to fail.
(I noticed this because the order is different depending if I run the tests from the cmd or using the IDE UI).

2- If I disable some random tests, and by doing so I reduce the number of tests that are run, the tests pass.

Which lead me to believe that the issue is actually related to the number of connections opened to the db, and it has nothing to do with my latest changes, I was just unlucky to implement the needed Nth test to cause the issue.

Furthermore, I noticed some logs that might give a clue to what's happening:

I noticed that the last few succesfull tests log:

```
2022-10-04 19:06:32.075  INFO 30978 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       transactionId: 160 userId:  : HikariPool-31 - Starting...
2022-10-04 19:06:32.106  INFO 30978 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       transactionId: 160 userId:  : HikariPool-31 - Start completed.
```

And these numbers start from 1 and grow until they reach 32, all followed by `HikariPool-N - Starting...` + `HikariPool-32 - Start completed.`.

After that, and exactly when the last tests will fail the logs print:

```
2022-10-04 19:06:36.653  INFO 30978 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean transactionId: 162 userId:  : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-04 19:06:36.654  INFO 30978 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       transactionId: 162 userId:  : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-10-04 19:06:36.655  INFO 30978 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       transactionId: 162 userId:  : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.


2022-10-04 19:06:36.664  WARN 30978 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   transactionId: 162 userId:  : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@23e88f43 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
```

followed by the logs shown above.

I am not sure where this 32 number is set, and if I should increase it. I tried to play around with hikari properties, starting with doubling the pool size from 10 to 20, but with no luck. I still get the same error.

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file for a clue.

Comment: Check whether postgres and ryuk images in your machine?

Comment: @YJR The test will initialize a new postgres container that remains even after it is done. And I noticed a `testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.1` container that stops after the test is done.
I guess I can check the postgres container and look for some logs as @LaurenzAlbe suggested.

Comment: Normaly when you finish executing test case both ryuk and postgres containers get stop

Comment: I think since we use the `withReuse(true)` option, it uses the same container?
I tried disabling that btw and it still didn't work.

Comment: `withReuse` only has an effect if reuse is also enabled in your `~/.testcontainers.properties` file. DId you manually enable reuse there?

Comment: @KevinWittek I just checked, it is enabled in the properties file as well.

Comment: As you pointed out above, it seems to be an issue with your connection pooling and likely not related to Testcontainers. Can you share a minimal reproducer?

Comment: I think it could be related to database-rider library. By any chance, those are the only tests without any db interaction? are you using any database-rider annotation at test class level? Looking at the logs is from the error is coming from. What if you move those tests to other test class using the stuff that is needed, taking into account the database is not.

Comment: @KevinWittek It might take a while for me to get to that, but I will try to play around with different ways to reproduce this later.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez I couldn't see any correlation between database-rider annotations and the failed tests, some times we use @DataSet() annotation, and when the order of tests is different there is no mention of database-rider whatsoever and I still get the same pooling error.

I should mention that all tests extends abstract classes that initialize the test container connection. even if those test classes don't use the database in there tests.

Comment: can you share part of your setup, please? maybe a github repository with some stuff from your project. I guess could be related to the number of transactions you are opening in your project and those are not closing somehow.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHumayed Did you find a solution? Same problem just happened in my app and it also uses DBRider with abstract base class for all tests. The logs are similar. HikariPool-1 is closed and then another tests tries to use it. It is only 4 (not 32) `HikariPool-*`s are created. Also I use [Database containers launched via JDBC URL scheme](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/) instead of explicitly created test containers.

Comment: @RuslanStelmachenko Unfortunately, I didn't. But it didn't matter, the project was abended anyway. I hope you can fix your problem though!

Comment: I debugged the problem and figured out that there are multiple bugs in DBRider related to closing and reusing DB connections. When `cacheConnection: true` one bug is happening, and when `cacheConnection: false` the other bug takes place. I created an [issue](https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider/issues/576) for the `cacheConnection: false` case, maybe it will be fixed sometime in the fiture. And for the `cacheConnection: true` case: it doesn't play nice with `@DirtiesContext` because DBRider caches and tries to reuse DB Connection from an already closed Spring Context.